# filling out tables and represent it to the clients

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am building a website for a Nutrition doctor, a doctor requested a diet regimen table on a monthly basis with five meals a day he is responsible for filling out tables which will be presented to the client and also he should be able to add,edit and remove them at anytime so what's the best way to add this system (filling out tables) to the website so the doctor can fill out these tables easily, also I have database for the exact meals that the doctor will provide to the clients and I need when the doctor focus on a cell the list of meals should appear that I stored in the database so he can choose from the list.
I am using HTML,css and js for front
nodejs express for back

Answer (score 0):

this is a very broad question, there are so many right answers.

Since you are using HTML, CSS And JS there are definitely NPM packages you could leverage for easily creating editable tables. I'd recommend a framework like react, angular or vue rather than using HTML/CSS/JS.

I can only really answer your question with my **personal preferences** so heres a few possibilities.

### Frontend

1. Material UI
2. html tables / grid / flex box

### Backend

1. Node.JS Express with a well defined restful api
2. firebase with firestore (this will make authentication simpler)